# Cannot add double to rule in boost::spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, rule

I try to add "double" for boost compiler example:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/calc8/

I can not add "double_type" to a rule:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, ast::operand(), ascii::space_type> unary_expr, primary_expr;
qi::double_type double_;

primary_expr = uint_ | double_ | identifier | bool_ | '(' > expr > ')';
```

Because code VS2k13 get an error:

> error C2668: 'boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply::initializer_node::initialize' : ambiguous call to overloaded function...

I also try to add long_type for example and this is not working too, but other types like hex_type works fine.

So I can not have multiple numeric types in one rule?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d79bb4f75b2e8392 vs http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02dac428b9e47294

Comment: ~thx u save my life :)